# Can you bypass the "AuthenticateRequest" portion of an IIS request

Tags: iis, azure, owin, newrelic

While looking at the New Relic logs for an Azure website (.Net MVC, Owin 3.0.1) it says our servers are spending 8.56% of total wall clock CPU serving favicon.ico*, with 95.9% of that time on the "AuthenticateRequest" step.

Is it possible to "bypass" any authentication when serving resources that are not protected/require no user information?  Any hints of where to look to figure out what is happening in that step?

[image: New Relic breakdown table]

- I have some ideas as to why we are serving favicon.ico so much which can be reduced, but I would like to apply this fix globally to a lot of other parts of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issues were entirely due to Owin 3.0.1 upgrade, downgrading to Owin 3.0.0 dropped my total CPU load by about 85%, Database by about 50%, and this particular screenshot from 66.7MS to 1.2 MS on the AuthenticateRequest step.